# How do I set up a custom header for specific categories archives on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to add a specific header image for each category and archive page.

Currently, i'm using the "Newswire" theme for wordpress, and my goal is to get a different header picture depending on the archive page (the category may be tricky because some post may fall between multiple categories, what then?)

I've tried plugins like taxonomy images, wp display header, category images and category logo without success.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the posts do fall into multiple categories, when you go to category archive page you will only see that specific category and posts within that category.

In order to get image in the header you would have to create custom category template:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

After that in order to have a featured image per category you will need to add custom field to the taxonomy.
For that you will need something like this:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

And then within the category template all you need to do is grab the image from that category probably using get_field('featured_image'); or similar depends on how do you call your field.